# Url with public

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-5

I am using laravel and deployed my application on server 
application folder path /var/www/app

So when i run the url with public, css will load.
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app/public/

But when i remove the public from url, css will not load.
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/app/

Css and js files are located into the public folder

How can i solve this issue, can i change the asset path if yes please tell me the where the asset define

Thanks

Comment: How are you accessing your css in your blade files?

Comment: yes definitely, i am usign default.blade.php file for include all the css and js file

Comment: Yes, but are you using the asset(''); helper method´?

Comment: So what can i do now, please assist

Comment: Except the welcome page, other module not open, page not found error occure. is this becouse i place the app folder into www forlder not in html folder

Comment: You should place all the css and js files in the public folder.Then you can access them in blade views by calling {{asset('path to files here')}}.And to avoid putting 'public' part in the url, you can point the server to public directory directly.

Comment: its working but with public/index.php in url :(

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is designed to run the code from the public directory, so files like `.env` are protected from public access. Your server should be pointed to the `public` folder.

However, if you want to change the public url, you can edit the index.php file and specify your own path:

```
// add after $app = require_once... in index.php
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try running `php artisan storage:link`